# Google Protobuf , .proto file query

Tags: protocol-buffers, akka-persistence

I need to create .proto file for following CRMData case class.
I am having confusion with the following datatypes i.e Nested Maps and user defined class (ShipToGroup)

```
case class CRMData(
       var customerShipToGroups : Map[String, Map[UUID, ShipToGroup]],
       var shipToGroups : Map[UUID, ShipToGroup],
       var shipToGroupLastUsed : UUID,
       var defaultShipToGroup : UUID
)

case class ShipToGroup(
    var customerUUID : String,
    var shipToGroupUUID : UUID,
    var name : String,
    var address : String,
    var companyName : String,
    var phoneNumber : Long,
    var city : String,
    var state : String,
    var zip : Int,
    var country : String,
    var landmark : String,
    var addressType : Int,
    var emailId : String,
    var addedAsBillingAddress : Boolean,
    var usedAsBillingAddress: Boolean,
    var isDefault : Boolean,
    var address2 : String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem you're going to have is that guids (I assume that is what `UUID` is) aren't a primitive type in .proto, and `map<,>` in .proto only works with string and integer types. I'm going to assume you're happy to use `string` as the closest match (and because it works in maps).

You can't do *nested maps*, but you can have a map where each element is something that *has* a map.

Combine those two caveats, and you can do something like:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message CRMData {
    map<string, NeedAGoodName> customerShipToGroups = 1;
    map<string, ShipToGroup> shipToGroups = 2;
    string shipToGroupLastUsed = 3;
    string defaultShipToGroup = 4;
}
message NeedAGoodName {
    map<string, ShipToGroup> items = 1;
}
message ShipToGroup {
    string customerUUID = 1;
    string shipToGroupUUID = 2;
    // ...
    string address2 = 17;
}
```

Note: it *might look* like I'm using `string` throughout, but that's just because of the specific example; .proto [supports more primitives than that](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) - I would expect to see some `bool` and `uint32` in your final version. Maybe some `fixed64` for the phone number, although a string might be more common for that. You might also want an [`enum`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum) for the `addressType`.

Comment: Hi Thanks this worked for me, now i m stuck with how to serialize CRMData which we are using above.